# Accessing Text Keyword Field through a Script

Tags: elasticsearch

I am trying to do some scripting in elasticsearch
Here is an example of the JSON segment in the request.

```
{
    "script_score": {
        "script": {
            "source": "doc.containsKey('var')?params.adder[doc['var'].keyword]:0 ",
            "params": {
                "adder": {
                    "type1": 1,
                    "type2": 1000
                }
            }
        }
    },
    "weight": 100000
}
```

This is the error that is thrown

```
{
                "shard": 0,
                "index": "",
                "node": "4eX6EgO2QAuBdc5zkUiDBg",
                "reason": {
                    "type": "script_exception",
                    "reason": "runtime error",
                    "script_stack": [
                        "org.elasticsearch.index.mapper.TextFieldMapper$TextFieldType.fielddataBuilder(TextFieldMapper.java:759)",
                        "org.elasticsearch.index.fielddata.IndexFieldDataService.getForField(IndexFieldDataService.java:116)",
                        "org.elasticsearch.index.query.QueryShardContext.lambda$lookup$0(QueryShardContext.java:290)",
                        "org.elasticsearch.search.lookup.LeafDocLookup$1.run(LeafDocLookup.java:101)",
                        "org.elasticsearch.search.lookup.LeafDocLookup$1.run(LeafDocLookup.java:98)",
                        "java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:312)",
                        "org.elasticsearch.search.lookup.LeafDocLookup.get(LeafDocLookup.java:98)",
                        "org.elasticsearch.search.lookup.LeafDocLookup.get(LeafDocLookup.java:41)",
                        "doc.containsKey('var')?params.adder[doc['var'].keyword]:0 ",
                        "                                           ^---- HERE"
                    ],
                    "script": "doc.containsKey('var')?params.adder[doc['var'].keyword]:0 ",
                    "lang": "painless",
                    "caused_by": {
                        "type": "illegal_argument_exception",
                        "reason": "Fielddata is disabled on text fields by default. Set fielddata=true on [var] in order to load fielddata in memory by uninverting the inverted index. Note that this can however use significant memory. Alternatively use a keyword field instead."
                    }
                }
            }
```

It's surprising to me that they cannot access the keyword field because it's nested. Do I need to make another field that is the keyword field?

Thank you

Comment: I think that you looking in wring direction. In `caused_by` part of your error you can read the description of problem. Your field type is `text` , and to use fielddata you need to set `fielddata=true` (but this is not recommended), or (better)  change your document mapping to keyword.

Comment: var is a text field. but var.keyword is a keyword field. But the code stops at "var" and doesn't find var.keyword

Comment: Try `doc['var.keyword']` or `doc['var.keyword'].value`

Comment: HAHA that worked. wow.

Comment: can you accept answer please?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To access nested fields try `doc['var.keyword']` or `doc['var.keyword'].value`